# Slugify within a static tag in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In one of my templates I use

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
    ...
    <img src="{% static 'img/{{ key|slugify }}.jpg' %}"/>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

but the output is not the one expected so I guess that one cannot use template filters within a `static` tag.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this then?

Edit: the keys of the dict above are strings that corresponds to the filenames of the jpg images.

Comment: what is the error you're experiencing? why not storing the images as objects with a `slug` field?

Comment: The error was a sort of "urlencoded" string instead of the filename (even though there were no special or nonlatin characters in the key). As far as the image as objects question, I don't want the extra queries to the db for the specific images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static) tag:

```
{% load static %}
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
    ...
    <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{ key|slugify }}.jpg"/>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```